# Namenode service fails during Hadoop Windows Installation

Tags: windows, hadoop, installation, hortonworks-data-platform

I am trying to install Hadoop for Windows 2.0.6 by Hortonworks on Windows Server 2008 R2.
I am setting up a single node instance; I was able to successfully install it but am facing errors while starting the services.

When I run the command start_local_hdp_services, only 9 out of 12 services are successfully started. Namenode, datanode, and secondarynamenode services have failed to start.

Why are these primary services failing?

This was the error. I got the same error for namenode, datanode, and secondarynamenode:

> Start-Service : Service 'Apache Hadoop namenode (namenode)' cannot be started due to the following error:
>   Cannot start service namenode on computer '.'.
>       At G:\Hadoop\manage_local_hdp_services.ps1:77 char:29
>       +         $foo = Start-Service <<<<  -Name $serviceName.Name -ErrorAction Continue
>       + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service], ServiceCommandException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotStartService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand

Comment: Are there any error messages? Posting it could help to diagnose the issue.

Comment: Yes, I updated the post with the error message. Thank you!